# How to enable only ArrowButton of DropDownButton control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a Devexpress **DropdownButton** control in my winform application. thing is i want to **enable** only the **ArrowButton** of DropdownButton control while DropdownButton will be **disabled**.

business is in some case i only want to execute the action which is defined inside the ArrowButton of DropdownButton but not the action defined inside the DropdownButton click.

the question may be silly. but i want to know is it possible or not?

Comment: The DropDownButton do not have a separate property to disable the "button" part of the control. It can be enabled or disabled entirely. As a workaround, implement this functionality inside your button click handler. For example, take into account some state variable.

Comment: If you want to execute only the action which is defined inside the ArrowButton of DropdownButton, you can set `DropDownButton.DropDownArrowStyle` property to `DevExpress.XtraEditors.DropDownArrowStyle.Show` value.